# Which bundles are attached to the tangle when closing a Flash Channel?

Tags: attach-to-tangle, flash-channel

I have a general question about closing a flash channel. My understanding is that when closing a flash channel the final bundle (the transfer from a leaf node/multisig to output addresses) is published and attached to the tangle. However, to my knowledge, the tangle at this point knows only about the the transfer used to open the channel which was a bundle transferring tokens into the deposit multisig (the root of the flash "tree").

**How will the tangle know the bundles generated to transfer tokens from the root node down to the leaf node if only the bundle transferring tokens from the leaf to the settlement addresses is attached to the tangle?.**

My understanding and terminology might be wrong, and maybe all of the bundles required to "sink" tokens from the root to the leaf need to be attached to the main network including the final bundle (as in the question above). I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me on this matter, or redirect me elsewhere :) Thank you in advance.